# Mongo DB Installation not Working with PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, centos

I am trying to install MongoDB with PHP5.2 on CentOS. When I run `phpinfo()` it says Mongo is not installed. I believe the PHP is working fine. I installed MongoDB, and I can enter the shell. I did `pecl install Mongo`, says it was completed and installed properly. I add a `mongo.in`i file which is `extension=mongo.so`. I can go to `/usr/lib64/php/modules/` and `mongo.so` is there. Is there anything I am forgetting? I have restarted both HTTPD and Mongod services.

Comment: Do you see mongo.ini in the list of parsed ini files ? Look at the very first table of the phpinfo() command.

Comment: Yeah, i have other inis there too like mysql.ini that are all being read

Comment: try running `php -v` in the console and see whether any startup errors pop up

Comment: yes, thank you, there is an error in the mongo file, undefined symbol: Z_DEFLREF_P in Unkown on line 0

I'll look around for an answer to that, but do you happen to know what it is?

Comment: I'd guess something wrong with the installed extension. I know centos has ext_mongo available as rpm. Try installing it from there.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I did for mongo driver 1.2.9 to work with php was

```
$ cd mongodb-php-driver-folder
$ phpize
$ ./configure
$ sudo make install
```

At the end of php.ini, add

```
extension=mongo.so
```

Restart apache.

Answer (score 1):

If something like an undefined symbol is showing up, it means that the source didn't compile properly. However, "Z_DEFLREF_P" is not part of the Mongo PHP Driver source code (in the latest version). Are you sure the error doesn't mention "Z_DELREF_P"?

Right now, that is indeed a bug in the 1.2.9 version of the driver. It doesn't compile with PHP 5.2 right now. I've added a ticket at https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-335

Answer (score 1):

Use the 1.2.7 mongo driver for php and you shouldn't have an issue compiling.